# `There is already an open DataReader` error when iterating over query results

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ado.net

Inside my foreach I assign a new var that I need in each iteration but I get an error:

```
 public ActionResult question(int? id)
 {
      if (id == null)
      {
          return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
      }
      var announcedAmount = db.AnnouncedAmount.Find(id);
      if (announcedAmount == null)
      {
          return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
      }
      decimal amount = announcedAmount.AmountAnnounced;
      var statusOne = db.Dabstats.Single(a => a.StatusName == "Request");
      var statusTwo = db.Dabstats.Single(a => a.StatusName == "Sold");

      var requests = db.Requests.Where(a => a.annId == id && a.statId == statusOne.statId).OrderBy(a => a.OfferRate);
      foreach (var item in requests)
      {
           decimal sold = requests.Where(a => a.statId == statusTwo.statId).Sum(a => a.soldAmount);
           decimal available = amount - sold;
           if (available >= item.reqAmount)
           {
                item.soldAmount = item.reqAmount;
                item.StatusId = statusOne.StatusId;
           }
           db.SaveChanges();
      }

      return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = AnnouncedAmount.annId});
}
```

The line of the error is:

```
decimal sold = requests.Where(a => a.statId == statusTwo.statId).Sum(a => a.soldAmount);
```

And the error message:

> There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which
>   must be closed first.

Any help, thank you very much

Comment: Did you try to add ToArray() on the request which is before your loop ?

Comment: Please use appropriate tags. This error has nothing to do with ASP.NET or `foreach`. You get the error when using ADO.NET and/or Entity Framework. In fact you'll find many duplicate questions if you search for this message.

Comment: I'm not sure this query makes any sense: First you query requests with the `Request` status, then you try to filter the *results* with the `Sold` status. No results can be both `Request` and `Sold` at the same time. What are you trying to do? There's probably a far simpler and faster query that will return what you want

Comment: Probably inside the loop where `requests` was used, it should have been `db.Requests`.

Comment: @Cubi, it will change the status of all related rows

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run proration using ASP.NET MVC 5 and ASP.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40981935/how-to-run-proration-using-asp-net-mvc-5-and-asp-net)

Answer (score 4):

The way you created the `foreach`-loop the DB is read on each iteration. Query the DB at once and it should work:

```
foreach (var item in requests.ToList())
```

Otherwise the `DataReader` for your `requests` query is still open when you query the DB for `requests.Where(a => a.statId == statusTwo.statId).Sum(a => a.soldAmount)` which is sent to the DB again.

If you add the `ToList()` to your initial query like:

```
var requests = db.Requests
                 .Where(a => a.annId == id && a.statId == statusOne.statId)
                 .OrderBy(a => a.OfferRate)
                 .ToList();
```

The DB is only queried once and the count in the loop is done in-memory.

**Update:**
I *guess* what you want is something like the following:

```
var requests = db.Requests
                 .Where(a => a.annId == id && a.statId == statusOne.statId)
                 .OrderBy(a => a.OfferRate)
                 .ToList();
foreach (var item in requests)
{
       decimal sold = db.Requests
                        .Where(a => a.annId == id && a.statId == statusTwo.statId)
                        .Sum(a => a.soldAmount);
       decimal available = amount - sold;
       if (available >= item.reqAmount)
       {
            item.soldAmount = item.reqAmount;
            item.StatusId = statusOne.StatusId;
       }
       db.SaveChanges();
  }
```

Comment: Even that won't work though, as the OP is trying to filter the *results* with a different status. The result will always be 0. This looks like either missing mappings or a badly expressed aggregate query

Comment: after change, it will run but there is error which @PanagiotisKanavos explained, the if condition inside the foreach each will be always true because sold amount is zero and will not check it

Comment: @ChrFin I am I doing right, I need to check inside foreach each rows then proceed

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40981935/how-to-run-proration-using-asp-net-mvc-5-and-asp-net

Answer (score 2):

As said, the underlying `DbDataReader` that executes the database reads is open while you execute the loop. Inside the loop you execute another query, so a new result set is requested while the connection open. By default, ADO.Net doesn't allow this. There are several ways to fix this:

1. Set `MultipleActiveResultSets=true` ([MARS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cfa084cz(v=vs.110).aspx)) in the connection string.
2. Materialize the query before the loop starts. Now inside the loop you can start new reads.
3. Reorganize your code. Looking more closely, it seems to me that you don't need the repeated read of the sold amount. You can keep track of `available` locally (unless this amount changes externally by concurrent users):

   ```
   var requests = db.Requests.Where(a => a.annId == id && a.statId == statusOne.statId).OrderBy(a => a.OfferRate);
   decimal sold = requests.Where(a => a.statId == statusTwo.statId).Sum(a => a.soldAmount);
   decimal available = amount - sold;
   foreach (var item in requests)
   {
       if (available >= item.reqAmount)
       {
           item.soldAmount = item.reqAmount;
           item.StatusId = statusOne.StatusId;
           available -= item.reqAmount;
       }
   }
   db.SaveChanges();
   ```

Materializing the query before the loop may seem an attractive option, but keep in mind that you pull data into memory, while reading during the loop executes the query in streaming mode. If great amounts of data are involved this may be a consideration.

Comment: this was really good, but I tried single transaction; I will change one and save then I will change other so that how I will be able to check the available amount.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this format:

```
foreach (var item in Requests)
            {
              var itemEdit = db.Requests.where(s=>s.Id == item.Id).FirstOrDefault();
                decimal sold = Requests.Where(a => a.statId == StatusTwo.statId).Sum(a => a.soldAmount);
                decimal available = amount - sold;
                if (available >= item.reqAmount)
                {
                    itemEdit.soldAmount = item.reqAmount;
                    itemEdit.StatusId = StatusOne.StatusId;
                }
                db.Entry(itemEdit).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
```

Comment: What format? How is this different from the original code and why does it fix the OP's problem? If anything, it seems that *another* bug is introduced by double-loading the same entity. If the original query suffered from an `N+1` issue, now it's `2N+1`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40981935/how-to-run-proration-using-asp-net-mvc-5-and-asp-net

Comment: Yeah, this only makes thing worse. It adds another read. Also, code-only answers are pretty useless without at least a brief explanation of why you think it solves the problem. Anybody can fire a blind shot an hope for some sloppy reader to vote it up.

Comment: Flagged as "not an answer" because it's still code-only.